# Proof that two generating function are equals for the sequence which $n$-th number is:

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

I am not sure I am doing this exercise good

1) $p_n $ | all parts are pairs different

and

2) $p_n $| all parts are not higher than $m$

I found these functions in book, first is:

$$ \prod_{i=1}^\infty (1+x^i)$$

And second:

$$ \prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-x^{2i-1})^{-1}$$

And I have to proof that those two functions are equals.

so:

Then I found something like this:

$$ (1+x^i) =  \left(\frac{1-x^{2i}}{1-x^i}\right) $$

Then i calculated right side to check it

$$ \left(\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^1}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x^2}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x^3}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^8}{1-x^4}\right)\cdots = \frac{1}{1-x^{2i-1}} $$

So this seems to be proof for this example but i dont know how i can find it by myself that

$$ 1+x^i =  \frac{1-x^{2i}}{1-x^i} $$

I dont know how to get this step. I will be very thankful for every help.

Comment: It's a difference of squares factorization.

Comment: I see but how I could know to change it to this way? not the other?
I mean when i got question like this on exam and I have got very little time is there any trick to get to this form very fast?

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto @Qiaochu point, all the author did was multiply by the difference i.e. $$\frac{1-x^i}{1-x^i}=1\\ \prod(1+x^i)\times1=\prod(1+x^i)\times\frac{1-x^i}{1-x^i}$$
Then I suppose if you were asked this in the exam, and only had $$\prod(1+x^i)=\prod(1-x^{2n-1})^{-1}$$

You could try switching the inverses $$\prod(1+x^i)^{-1}=\prod(1-x^i+x^{2i}-x^{3-i} \cdots)$$
Then think "how can I only get odd terms from this?", recognise this simple identity trick
$$\frac{1-a}{1-a^2}=\frac{1}{(1+a)(1-a)}$$
The difference of squares, and this will remove all even terms.